# Performance Mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, count, sum

I have a query to the database using a lot COUNT and SUM. With a large amount of records it queries very slowly (approximately 1 second / 300 logs) and often out of memory. In my query a table can query multiple times with different WHERE conditions. Is there a way to optimize it?

```
SELECT
                Waiting.w_waiting, Active.w_accept, Cancel.w_cancel,
                Notwork.w_notwork,Inwork.w_inwork,Precheck.w_precheck,
                Task.id,Task.case_id,Task.customer_id,Task.created,Task.interpreter_id,Task.high_light,Task.is_test,
                Task.redo,Task.deliveryProduction,Task.accept_assign,Task.qc_checking_id,
                Task.interpreter_id,Task.check_interpreter,Task.jobTitle,Task.amount,Task.isExpress,
                Task.is_ready,Task.status,Task.vip_job,Task.is_final_assigned,Task.sub_status,
                Task.jobInfo,Task.jobInfoProduction,Task.jobInfo_trans,Task.jobInfoProduction_trans,Task.customer_id,
                Qc_waitcheck.waitcheck,Qc_done.qc_done,
                Qc_ready.qc_ready,Qc_redo.qc_redo,Qc_redo_done.qc_redo_done,
                W_inwork.inwork,Task.customer_workflow_id,Task.workflow_activated,Task.superqc,Task.is_temp_stop,
                COALESCE(Upload_New, 0) AS Upload_New, COALESCE(Upload_Int, 0) AS Upload_Int, COALESCE(Upload_Ext, 0) AS Upload_Ext,
                COALESCE(Upload_All, 0) AS Upload_All, COALESCE(Accepted_Files, 0) AS Accepted_Files, COALESCE(Check_Int, 0) AS Check_Int,
                COALESCE(Check_Ext, 0) AS Check_Ext,  COALESCE(All_Files, 0) AS All_Files
            FROM tasks AS Task
            LEFT JOIN staff_jobs AS SJ ON SJ.task_id = Task.id
            LEFT JOIN 
                (
                    SELECT COUNT(SJ.id) AS w_waiting, SJ.task_id AS task_id 
                    FROM staff_jobs AS SJ 
                    WHERE SJ.is_waiting = 1 
                    GROUP BY SJ.task_id
                ) AS Waiting ON Waiting.task_id = Task.id 
            LEFT JOIN 
                (
                    SELECT COUNT(SJ.id) AS w_accept, SJ.task_id AS task_id 
                    FROM staff_jobs AS SJ 
                    WHERE SJ.is_waiting = 0 AND SJ.actived = 1 
                    GROUP BY SJ.task_id
                ) AS Active ON Active.task_id = Task.id 
            LEFT JOIN 
                (
                    SELECT COUNT(SJ.id) AS w_cancel, SJ.task_id AS task_id 
                    FROM staff_jobs AS SJ 
                    WHERE SJ.is_waiting = 0 AND SJ.actived = 0 
                    GROUP BY SJ.task_id
                ) AS Cancel ON Cancel.task_id = Task.id 
            LEFT JOIN 
                (
                    SELECT COUNT(SJ.id) AS w_notwork, SJ.task_id AS task_id 
                    FROM staff_jobs AS SJ 
                    WHERE SJ.status = 0 AND SJ.actived = 1 
                    GROUP BY SJ.task_id
                ) AS Notwork ON Notwork.task_id = Task.id 
            LEFT JOIN 
                (
                    SELECT COUNT(SJ.id) AS w_inwork, SJ.task_id AS task_id 
                    FROM staff_jobs AS SJ 
                    WHERE SJ.status = 1 AND SJ.actived = 1 
                    GROUP BY SJ.task_id
                ) AS Inwork ON Inwork.task_id = Task.id 
            LEFT JOIN 
                (
                    SELECT COUNT(SJ.id) AS w_precheck, SJ.task_id AS task_id 
                    FROM staff_jobs AS SJ 
                    WHERE SJ.status = 3 AND SJ.actived = 1 
                    GROUP BY SJ.task_id
                ) AS Precheck ON Precheck.task_id = Task.id
            LEFT JOIN 
                (
                    SELECT COUNT(StaffJob.id) AS inwork, StaffJob.task_id AS task_id 
                    FROM staff_jobs AS StaffJob 
                    WHERE StaffJob.status >= 3
                    GROUP BY StaffJob.task_id 
                ) AS W_inwork ON W_inwork.task_id = Task.id
            LEFT JOIN 
                (
                    SELECT COUNT(StaffPic.id) AS waitcheck, StaffPic.task_id AS task_id 
                    FROM staff_pics AS StaffPic 
                    WHERE StaffPic.status = 3
                    GROUP BY StaffPic.task_id 
                ) AS Qc_waitcheck ON Qc_waitcheck.task_id = Task.id
            LEFT JOIN 
                (
                    SELECT COUNT(BRDONE.id) AS qc_done, BRDONE.task_id AS task_id 
                    FROM br24dones AS BRDONE 
                    WHERE BRDONE.rating IS NOT NULL AND BRDONE.rating > 0 
                    GROUP BY BRDONE.task_id 
                ) AS Qc_done ON Qc_done.task_id = Task.id  
            LEFT JOIN 
                (
                    SELECT COUNT(BRDONE.id) AS qc_ready, BRDONE.task_id AS task_id 
                    FROM br24dones AS BRDONE 
                    WHERE BRDONE.is_ready = 1
                    GROUP BY BRDONE.task_id 
                ) AS Qc_ready ON Qc_ready.task_id = Task.id  
            LEFT JOIN 
                (
                    SELECT COUNT(StaffPic.id) AS qc_redo, StaffPic.task_id AS task_id 
                    FROM staff_pics AS StaffPic 
                    WHERE StaffPic.redo > 0 
                    GROUP BY StaffPic.task_id 
                ) AS Qc_redo ON Qc_redo.task_id = Task.id
            LEFT JOIN 
                (
                    SELECT COUNT(StaffPic.id) AS qc_redo_done, StaffPic.task_id AS task_id 
                    FROM staff_pics AS StaffPic 
                    WHERE StaffPic.redo > 0 AND StaffPic.status = 3
                    GROUP BY StaffPic.task_id 
                ) AS Qc_redo_done ON Qc_redo_done.task_id = Task.id 
            LEFT JOIN
                (SELECT SUM(Upload_New) AS Upload_New, StaffJob.task_id AS task_id FROM staff_jobs AS StaffJob 
                    LEFT JOIN 
                        (SELECT COUNT(OP.id) AS Upload_New, OP.job_id AS task_id FROM outputs AS OP 
                        GROUP BY OP.staff_job_id, OP.job_id) AS Upload_New 
                    ON Upload_New.task_id = StaffJob.task_id 
                WHERE StaffJob.type = 0
                GROUP BY StaffJob.task_id) AS Upload_New
            ON Upload_New.task_id = Task.id
            LEFT JOIN
                (SELECT SUM(Upload_Int) AS Upload_Int, StaffJob.task_id AS task_id FROM staff_jobs AS StaffJob 
                    LEFT JOIN 
                        (SELECT COUNT(OP.id) AS Upload_Int, OP.job_id AS task_id FROM outputs AS OP 
                        GROUP BY OP.staff_job_id, OP.job_id) AS Upload_Int 
                    ON Upload_Int.task_id = StaffJob.task_id 
                WHERE StaffJob.type = 1
                GROUP BY StaffJob.task_id) AS Upload_Int
            ON Upload_Int.task_id = Task.id
            LEFT JOIN
                (SELECT SUM(Upload_Ext) AS Upload_Ext, StaffJob.task_id AS task_id FROM staff_jobs AS StaffJob 
                    LEFT JOIN 
                        (SELECT COUNT(OP.id) AS Upload_Ext, OP.job_id AS task_id FROM outputs AS OP 
                        GROUP BY OP.staff_job_id, OP.job_id) AS Upload_Ext 
                    ON Upload_Ext.task_id = StaffJob.task_id 
                WHERE StaffJob.type = 2
                GROUP BY StaffJob.task_id) AS Upload_Ext
            ON Upload_Ext.task_id = Task.id
            LEFT JOIN
                (SELECT Upload_All AS Upload_All, StaffJob.task_id AS task_id FROM staff_jobs AS StaffJob 
                    LEFT JOIN 
                        (SELECT COUNT(OP.id) AS Upload_All, OP.job_id AS task_id FROM outputs AS OP 
                        GROUP BY OP.job_id) AS Upload_All 
                    ON Upload_All.task_id = StaffJob.task_id 
                ) AS Upload_All
            ON Upload_All.task_id = Task.id
            LEFT JOIN   
                (SELECT COUNT(BR_CHECK.id) AS Accepted_Files, BR_CHECK.task_id AS task_id FROM br24dones AS BR_CHECK 
                 WHERE BR_CHECK.intern_redo_id IS NULL AND BR_CHECK.extern_redo_id IS NULL GROUP BY BR_CHECK.task_id) AS CHECKING
            ON CHECKING.task_id = Task.id
            LEFT JOIN   
                (SELECT COUNT(BR_INT.id) AS Check_Int, BR_INT.task_id AS task_id FROM br24dones AS BR_INT
                 WHERE BR_INT.intern_redo_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY BR_INT.task_id) AS INTERNAL
            ON INTERNAL.task_id = Task.id
            LEFT JOIN   
                (SELECT COUNT(BR_EXT.id) AS Check_Ext, BR_EXT.task_id AS task_id FROM br24dones AS BR_EXT
                 WHERE BR_EXT.extern_redo_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY BR_EXT.task_id) AS EXTERNAL
            ON EXTERNAL.task_id = Task.id
            LEFT JOIN   
                (SELECT COUNT(BR_ALL.id) AS All_Files, BR_ALL.task_id AS task_id FROM br24dones AS BR_ALL
                GROUP BY BR_ALL.task_id) AS DONE_ALL
            ON DONE_ALL.task_id = Task.id GROUP BY Task.id
```

Comment: Part of the slowdown is that `JOIN ( SELECT ... ) JOIN ( SELECT ... )` does not optimize well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a lot.

You can remove quite a few duplicate joins. Just join once and do the group by afterwards. For the counts in the select you can give use an if statement to only count those with the right statuses.

I don't have the information nor the time to show you this fully but you have to cut down on the subqueries. remember that for each row all those subqueries will be executed (and if you have another subquery within a subquery those numbers can add up to a lot.)

to take the first few joins

```
SELECT
            Waiting.w_waiting, Active.w_accept, Cancel.w_cancel,
            Notwork.w_notwork,Inwork.w_inwork,Precheck.w_precheck,
            Task.id,Task.case_id,Task.customer_id,Task.created,Task.interpreter_id,Task.high_light,Task.is_test,
            Task.redo,Task.deliveryProduction,Task.accept_assign,Task.qc_checking_id,
            Task.interpreter_id,Task.check_interpreter,Task.jobTitle,Task.amount,Task.isExpress,
            Task.is_ready,Task.status,Task.vip_job,Task.is_final_assigned,Task.sub_status,
            Task.jobInfo,Task.jobInfoProduction,Task.jobInfo_trans,Task.jobInfoProduction_trans,Task.customer_id,
            Qc_waitcheck.waitcheck,Qc_done.qc_done,
            Qc_ready.qc_ready,Qc_redo.qc_redo,Qc_redo_done.qc_redo_done,
            W_inwork.inwork,Task.customer_workflow_id,Task.workflow_activated,Task.superqc,Task.is_temp_stop,
            COALESCE(Upload_New, 0) AS Upload_New, COALESCE(Upload_Int, 0) AS Upload_Int, COALESCE(Upload_Ext, 0) AS Upload_Ext,
            COALESCE(Upload_All, 0) AS Upload_All, COALESCE(Accepted_Files, 0) AS Accepted_Files, COALESCE(Check_Int, 0) AS Check_Int,
            COALESCE(Check_Ext, 0) AS Check_Ext,  COALESCE(All_Files, 0) AS All_Files
        FROM tasks AS Task
        LEFT JOIN staff_jobs AS SJ ON SJ.task_id = Task.id
        LEFT JOIN 
            (
                SELECT COUNT(SJ.id) AS w_waiting, SJ.task_id AS task_id 
                FROM staff_jobs AS SJ 
                WHERE SJ.is_waiting = 1 
                GROUP BY SJ.task_id
            ) AS Waiting ON Waiting.task_id = Task.id 
        LEFT JOIN 
            (
                SELECT COUNT(SJ.id) AS w_accept, SJ.task_id AS task_id 
                FROM staff_jobs AS SJ 
                WHERE SJ.is_waiting = 0 AND SJ.actived = 1 
                GROUP BY SJ.task_id
            ) AS Active ON Active.task_id = Task.id 
        LEFT JOIN 
            (
                SELECT COUNT(SJ.id) AS w_cancel, SJ.task_id AS task_id 
                FROM staff_jobs AS SJ 
                WHERE SJ.is_waiting = 0 AND SJ.actived = 0 
                GROUP BY SJ.task_id
            ) AS Cancel ON Cancel.task_id = Task.id 
        LEFT JOIN 
            (
                SELECT COUNT(SJ.id) AS w_notwork, SJ.task_id AS task_id 
                FROM staff_jobs AS SJ 
                WHERE SJ.status = 0 AND SJ.actived = 1 
                GROUP BY SJ.task_id
            ) AS Notwork ON Notwork.task_id = Task.id 
        LEFT JOIN 
            (
                SELECT COUNT(SJ.id) AS w_inwork, SJ.task_id AS task_id 
                FROM staff_jobs AS SJ 
                WHERE SJ.status = 1 AND SJ.actived = 1 
                GROUP BY SJ.task_id
            ) AS Inwork ON Inwork.task_id = Task.id 
        LEFT JOIN 
            (
                SELECT COUNT(SJ.id) AS w_precheck, SJ.task_id AS task_id 
                FROM staff_jobs AS SJ 
                WHERE SJ.status = 3 AND SJ.actived = 1 
                GROUP BY SJ.task_id
            ) AS Precheck ON Precheck.task_id = Task.id
        LEFT JOIN 
            (
                SELECT COUNT(StaffJob.id) AS inwork, StaffJob.task_id AS task_id 
                FROM staff_jobs AS StaffJob 
                WHERE StaffJob.status >= 3
                GROUP BY StaffJob.task_id 
            ) AS W_inwork ON W_inwork.task_id = Task.id
```

This can be reduced to:

```
SELECT
            *,
            COALESCE(Upload_New, 0) AS Upload_New, COALESCE(Upload_Int, 0) AS Upload_Int, COALESCE(Upload_Ext, 0) AS Upload_Ext,
            COALESCE(Upload_All, 0) AS Upload_All, COALESCE(Accepted_Files, 0) AS Accepted_Files, COALESCE(Check_Int, 0) AS Check_Int,
            COALESCE(Check_Ext, 0) AS Check_Ext,  COALESCE(All_Files, 0) AS All_Files,
            SUM(IF(SJ.is_waiting = 1)) AS w_waiting,
            SUM(IF(SJ.is_waiting = 0 AND SJ.actived = 1)) AS w_accept,
            SUM(IF(SJ.is_waiting = 0 AND SJ.actived = 0)) AS w_cancel,
            SUM(IF(SJ.status = 0 AND SJ.actived = 1)) AS w_notwork,
            SUM(IF(SJ.status = 1 AND SJ.actived = 1)) AS w_inwork,
            SUM(IF(SJ.status = 3 AND SJ.actived = 1)) AS w_precheck,
            SUM(IF(SJ.status >= 1)) AS inwork
        FROM tasks AS Task
        LEFT JOIN staff_jobs AS SJ ON SJ.task_id = Task.id
        GROUP BY SJ.task_id
```

This removes 6 subqueries which all requested the same data.

This can be done for the other tables requested as well